# Foundation6 turn off SASS auto minify when compiled

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, zurb-foundation-6

I'm beginner with Foundation and Sass. I understand slowly how it works. The workflow seems great, but here's my "issue".

When my SCSS is compiled, my CSS minifies as soon as I save my `.scss` file.

I've tried to turn off the Gulp task, but it didn't do anything.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var sassPaths = [
  'bower_components/normalize.scss/sass',
  'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
  'bower_components/motion-ui/src'
];

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
//      outputStyle: 'compressed' 
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your task their shouldn't be any part of it that is minifying your css. A couple of things you could try:

1) Try `outputStyle: 'expanded'`

2) Try compiling your sass without including any of the bower sass files, as one of them could already be minified (although unlikely). Or even just check those manually.

3) Or finally try this configuration:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var sassPaths = [
  'bower_components/normalize.scss/sass',
  'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
  'bower_components/motion-ui/src',
  'scss/*.scss'
];

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(sassPaths)
    .pipe($.sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded' 
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```